# objective-c default init method for class?

Tags: objective-c, macos, initialization

I have two differing methods for initializing my objective-c class. One is the default, and one takes a configuration parameter. Now, I'm pretty green when it comes to objective-c, but I've implemented these methods and I'm wondering if there's a better (more correct/in good style) way to handle initialization than the way I have done it. Meaning, did I write these initialization functions in accordance with standards and good style? It just doesn't feel right to check for the existence of `selfPtr` and then return based on that.

Below are my class header and implementation files. Also, if you spot anything else that is wrong or evil, please let me know. I am a C++/Javascript developer who is learning objective-c as hobby and would appreciate any tips that you could offer.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

// class for raising events and parsing returned directives

@interface awesome : NSObject {
 // silence is golden. Actually properties are golden. Hence this emptiness.
}

// properties
@property (retain) SBJsonParser* parser;
@property (retain) NSString* eventDomain;
@property (retain) NSString* appid

// constructors
-(id) init;
-(id) initWithAppId:(id) input;

// destructor
-(void) dealloc;


@end
```

---

```
#import "awesome.h"
#import "JSON.h"


@implementation awesome



- (id) init {
 if (self = [super init]) {
  // if init is called directly, just pass nil to AppId contructor variant
  id selfPtr = [self initWithAppId:nil];
 }

 if (selfPtr) {
  return selfPtr;
 } else {
  return self;
 }
}

- (id) initWithAppId:(id) input {
 if (self = [super init]) {
  if (input = nil) {
   input = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"a369x123"];
  }
  [self setAppid:input];
  [self setEventDomain:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"desktop"]];
 }
 return self;
}

// property synthesis
@synthesize parser;
@synthesize appid;
@synthesize eventDomain;

// destructor
- (void) dealloc {
 self.parser = nil;
 self.appid = nil;
 self.eventDomain = nil;
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

***Thanks!***

Comment: One particular problem that I see is that if `init` is used, then `[super init]` is called twice.

Comment: You're also leaking the `eventDomain` property, because you create an object with +1 ownership count, and give it to a method that increases the ownership count to +2, your dealloc method only brings it back down to +1. It should be 0 relative to your `awesome` object.

Comment: Also, the `Cocoa/Cocoa.h` include is for Mac OS X, not for iOS.

Comment: Also, Cocoa traditionally uses capital camel case (or upper camel case) for class names, such as `Awesome` or `MoreAwesome`, or `TheMostAwesome` etc.

Comment: Wait, who added the `ios` tag? There was nothing in this question to suggest this was `ios`, in fact as @jer points out, the included header indicates that this is Mac OS X, not iOS.

Comment: This isn't relevant to the init methods, but a couple of unidiomatic things: 1) Class names should start with a capital letter. 2) You should simply release your instance variables in the `dealloc` method instead of setting the property to nil. So `[parser release]` and so on. This second point is because property setters may cause side effects that are not desirable when an object is being destroyed.

Comment: Another style issue: Acronyms are capitalized in Cocoa, e.g. -initWithAppID:, -UTF8String, -setURL:.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When one initializer simply performs the more complex initializer with some default parameters, call it as such:

```
-(id)init {
  return [self initWithAppID:nil];
}

-(id)initWithAppID:(id)input {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    /* perform your post-initialization logic here */
  }
  return self;
}
```

Usually you try to make one of the initializers the "designated initializer", meaning it's the one that always gets invoked.  In this case that's `-initWithAppID:`.

Answer (score 1):

Your init method should call the preferred initializer, initWithAppId:, instead of the super implementation. Then the initWithAppId calls the super implementation, as it does. Also, in initWithAppId:, you have if(input = nil), which will always set input to nil and evaluate to YES. Here are the proper implementations.

```
- (id)init {
    return [self initWithAppId:nil];
}
- (id)initWithAppId:(id)input {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        if(input == nil) input = @"a369x123";
        self.appid = input;
        self.eventDomain = @"desktop";
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I see this as a moot point. Your second initialization method makes no sense when receiving a nil argument (plus you have a logic problem in your conditional checking if input is nil). What I would do in this case, is provide one initialization method, and two factory class methods which act in the usual way: Return autoreleased instances, and in one of them, provide your default value.

For instance, declare a class method:

```
+ (awesome*)awesome;
+ (awesome*)awesomeWithAppId:(id)foo;
```

and in your implementation for `+awesome` for instance, write it like this:

```
+ (awesome*)awesome
{
    return [[[awesome alloc] initWithAppId:@"a369x123"] autorelease];
}
```

And likewise, in your `awesomeWithAppId:` something like this:

```
+ (awesome*)awesomeWithAppId:(id)foo
{
    return [[[awesome alloc] initWithAppId:foo] autorelease];
}
```

Then again, this may just be me.

Answer (score 0):

The `default` will be whichever one you choose to call,

```
[awesome alloc] init];
[awesome alloc] initWithAppId:ID];
```